# How to read ruby on rails config values from within the application controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, configuration

If i have a configuration file like this

```
# config/environments/integration.rb
config.action_controller.session = {
  :domain => ".example.com"
}
```

How do I get the value from within my application controller, e.g:

```
# app/controller/application_controller
class ApplicationController < Mcc::CoreSupport::FrontendController
  def some_method
    value = xxx
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The class method `ActionController::Base.session_options` returns a hash of the configuration options for the session.

So in your case you want  `ActionController::Base.session_options[:domain]`

Answer (score 69):

In Ruby on Rails 3 and above, you can access the config through `Rails.application.config`

---

In more recent versions, you can use `Rails.configuration` instead. For example: `Rails.configuration.time_zone`.
See more in the [official manual on configuration](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html)

Comment: Works on Rails 5.1.1